# Using pyodbc to pull data from 2 tables using unique date as reference

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an MS Access database which contains 2 tables; the first containing rows showing “dd/mm/yyy”, “hh:mm”, “price” – with each row showing data for the next incremental minute. Basically , intraday minute price data for a stock index.

The second table contains the following data; “dd/mm/yyy”, “Closing Price”, “volatility” – with volatility priced using a format of “15.55” for example. Each additional row shows information for the next incremental day.

So the first table has rows going up in minutes, the second has rows going up in days.

I would like to form a pyodbc query that pulls out data from the second table, based on the date and references it to the first table. So that I can get rows of data containing:
 “dd/mm/yy”, “hh:mm”, “price”, “closing price”, “volatility”.

The “closing price” and “volatility” values with then hopefully repeat themselves until the minutes tick over into the next day, and then they will update to show the next day’s values.

I am completely new to programming and have managed to do the following so far. I can pull each query down individually (and print them so I know what I am getting).

I know that the output below contains an additional “00:00:00” after the date – not 100% sure how to get rid of that – and I don’t think it is vital anyway as the dates should still be able to be referenced. (one problem at a time! ;))

Output from table one looks like this:

```
2005-01-03 00:00:00  17:00  1213.25
2005-01-03 00:00:00  17:01  1213.25
2005-01-03 00:00:00  17:02  1213.75
2005-01-03 00:00:00  17:03  1213.75
```

Output from table 2 looks like this:

```
2005-01-03 00:00:00  1206.25  14.08
2005-01-04 00:00:00  1191.00  13.98
2005-01-05 00:00:00  1183.25  14.09
2005-01-06 00:00:00  1188.25  13.58
```

here is my code so far:

```
from math import sqrt
import time
import pyodbc

"""establishes connection to the database and creates "cursors" with which to query data"""

ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE = "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\xy\\Apache         Python\\SandP.accdb"
ODBC_CONN_STR = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' % ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(ODBC_CONN_STR)
cursor1 = cnxn.cursor()
cursor2 = cnxn.cursor()


"""uses cursor1 to pull out distinct rows of data, ordered by distinct date/time"""

cursor1.execute("select distinct [Intraday_values].[Date_], Time_, Close from [Intraday_values] order by [Intraday_values].[Date_]")
row1 = cursor1.fetchall()
for row1 in row1:
print row1[0], row1[1], row1[2]
time.sleep(2)

"""uses cursor2 to pull out settlement prices and volatility data and order by distinct date"""

cursor2.execute("select distinct [Closing_prices].[Date_], Last_price, Volatility from [Closing_prices] order by [Closing_prices].[Date_]")
row2 = cursor2.fetchall()
for row2 in row2:
print row2[0], row2[1], row2[2]
time.sleep(2)
```

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated and may just save me from pulling the rest of my hair out….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you should be able to do that with a single query that JOINs both tables

```python
cursor1.execute(
    "select distinct iv.[Date_], iv.Time_, iv.Close, cp.Last_price, cp.Volatility " +
    "from [Intraday_values] AS iv INNER JOIN [Closing_prices] AS cp" +
    "    ON cp.[Date_] = iv.[Date_] " +
    "order by iv.[Date_], iv.Time_")
row1 = cursor1.fetchall()
for row1 in row1:
    print row1[0], row1[1], row1[2], row1[3], row1[4]
```

Comment: Ah that's amazing thank you so much - very quick response and does exactly what i wanted!!!

Comment: Apologies to bother you again, I was wondering if I could ask a further question related to the above query. Currently the closing price and volatility tick over into a new values at the stroke of midnight, with 00:01 shoring the new values for that day. If I wanted to pull down a query that included all the above data (“dd/mm/yy”, “hh:mm”, “price”, “closing price”, “volatility”) but the closing price and volatility began at 15:30 and changed over to the next day at 15:14 the next day. So for example the first values for "volatility" and "closing price" for 02/01/2014 would line up

Comment: with the intraday values at "2014-01-02 15:30" and then tick over to their new values onyt at "2014-01-03 15:14". Then the new volatility and closing prices values for 03/01/2014 would begin at 2014-01-03 15:30 and end at 2014-01-04 15:14 and so on....

Comment: And sorry i should also add that Fridays volatility and closing prices should begin Friday at 15:30 until Monday 15:14, and only then change to the new values. Apologies - I am very inexperienced with programming so this is just a little beyond me at this point

Comment: @user3253628 It sounds like you want to create a saved query in Access (or a subquery in your SQL statement) that calculates an [Effective_Date] for each row in [Intraday_values] and then join on [Effective_Date] instead of [Date_]. To do that for each day (neglecting the Friday-to-Monday thing) it would be something like `SELECT Date_, Time_, Close, DateAdd("d",IIf(Time_<#15:30#,-1,0),Date_) AS Effective_Date FROM Intraday_Values`. If you need more specific help you should probably [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Again thank you very much for your help, i have seen some similar code before, albeit in an excel VBA macro. I shall try to play around with the code you have provided, and then hopefully i can formulate a more concise question as you have suggested.